# WPF Динамическое отображение данных из DataTable в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

Изучаю вопрос наполнения DataGrid из DataTable с целью динамического формирования отображаемых данных.

Цель программы: Выполнения массовых запросов в множество баз данных и наполнения таблицы результатами из запросов. Соответственно в каждой из базы могут появляться n+ новых столбцов, и r+ записей.

Хотелось бы динамически отображать новые данные, но затык у меня произошел в самом начале визуализации данных: DataGrid напрочь отказывается отобразить информацию из DataTable, хотя в отладке я вижу, что информация корректно наполнилась в DataTable.

Был бы безмерно благодарен, если бы тыкнули пальцем где я неправ и что еще по своему незнанию забыл сделать? Скрещиваю два экземпляра в первые :-(

Для тестов реализовал маленькую программульку:

По кнопке выполняется наполнение DataTable во ViewModel

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = MainVm;
        }

        public ViewModel MainVm { get; } = new ViewModel();
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                MainVm.DataTable.Columns.Add("col1");
                MainVm.DataTable.Columns.Add("col2");
                var row = MainVm.DataTable.NewRow();
                row[0] = "test1";
                row[1] = "test2";
                MainVm.DataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Сама ViewModel:

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        public DataTable DataTable
        {
            get
            {
                return dataTable;
            }
            set
            {
                dataTable = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DataTable)));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Ну и само окно программы:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_Datagrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Datagrid"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450" Width="800"
>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Start</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding DataTable}" ItemsSource="{Binding DefaultView}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: DataTable не имеет внутри коллекций, которые умеют сообщать о том, что они изменились. Как это обычно делает ObservableCollection. Поэтому обновится он только если вы насильно ему перепишите связь: сначала обязательно занулить `myGrid.ItemsSource = null;` и потом `myGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSource;`. Но лучше перейти с DataTable на что-то более подходящее.

Comment: @AlexKrass а что можно использовать более подходящее, если я не знаю изначально сколько у меня строк и сколько столбцов будет после каждого запроса в базу? Ранее работал с datagrid только с жесткими структурами, а тут получается динамика как по высоте, так и по ширине :-(

Comment: Я для интереса попробовал что-то сделать, можете посмотреть в ответе, хотя конечно проще использовать первый вариант и не думать особо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый просто вариант обновлять данные перезаписью DataTable.

```
myGrid.ItemsSource = null;
myGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSource;
```

Можно так же изменять напрямую у DataGrid его колонки из кода, а сами данные связывать через `ObservableCollection`.

```
myGrid.Columns.Clear();
foreach(var header in Headers) 
{
    myGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() 
    { 
        Header = header.DisplayName, 
        Binding = new Binding(header.BindingName) 
    })
}
```

---

Можно заморочиться и кастомизировать DataGrid, чтобы работать только из VM с коллекциями и разорвать связь с View. Но я не уверен, что этот подход будет хорошим, мне просто было интересно попробовать и код можно еще долго улучшать.

**Header**

```
public class Header 
{ 
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string BindingName { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomDataGrid**

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Columns", 
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Header>), 
        typeof(CustomDataGrid), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(ColumnsPropertyCallback)));

    public new ObservableCollection<Header> Columns
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Header>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set {
            SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);   
        }
    }

    private static void ColumnsPropertyCallback(DependencyObject dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var customDataGrid = dp as CustomDataGrid;
        if (e.OldValue != null) 
        {
            customDataGrid.Columns.CollectionChanged -= customDataGrid.CustomColumns_CollectionChanged;
        }
            
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            customDataGrid.Columns.CollectionChanged += customDataGrid.CustomColumns_CollectionChanged;
        }
        customDataGrid.Refresh();
    }


    private void CustomColumns_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    private void Refresh() 
    {
        base.Columns.Clear();
        if (this.Columns != null)
            this.Columns.ToList().ForEach(header => base.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = header.DisplayName, Binding = new Binding(header.BindingName) }));
    }
}
```

**ViewModel класс с примером**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Header> customColumns = new ObservableCollection<Header>();
    public ObservableCollection<Header> CustomColumns
    {
        get { return customColumns; }
        set 
        {
            customColumns = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<object> customData = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    public ObservableCollection<object> CustomData
    {
        get { return customData; }
        set
        {
            customData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int counter = 1;

    private ICommand _btnClick;
    public ICommand BtnClick
    {
        get
        {
            if (_btnClick == null)
            {
                _btnClick = new RelayCommand(
                    p => true,
                    p => 
                    {
                        CustomColumns.Clear();
                        CustomData.Clear();
                        
                        dynamic v = null;
                        if (counter % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            CustomColumns.Add(new Header() { DisplayName = "ID", BindingName = "ID" });
                            CustomColumns.Add(new Header() { DisplayName = "Имя", BindingName = "Name" }) ;
                            CustomColumns.Add(new Header() { DisplayName = "Фамилия", BindingName = "Surname" });
                            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                            {
                                v = new { ID = i, Name = "Имя " + i, Surname = "Фамилия " + i };
                                CustomData.Add(v);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CustomColumns.Add(new Header() { DisplayName = "ID", BindingName = "ID" });
                            CustomColumns.Add(new Header() { DisplayName = "Кол-во товара", BindingName = "Amount" });
                            CustomColumns.Add(new Header() { DisplayName = "Цена", BindingName = "Price" });
                            CustomColumns.Add(new Header() { DisplayName = "Описание", BindingName = "Description" });
                            CustomColumns.Add(new Header() { DisplayName = "Поставщик", BindingName = "Retailer" });
                            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                            {
                                v = new { ID = i, Amount = i + i, Price = i + "$", Description = "Описание", Retailer = "Поставщик " + i };
                                CustomData.Add(v);
                            }
                        }
                        counter++;
                    });
            }
            return _btnClick;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Command="{Binding BtnClick}">Start</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <local:CustomDataGrid Grid.Row="1" Columns="{Binding CustomColumns}" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="xGrid"></local:CustomDataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Код View тогда получается пустой**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Код RelayCommand на всякий случай тоже прилагаю**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]